# XSLT (XML to XML) output contains non-matching data from source

Tags: xslt

Using Visual Studio to perform the transform during development the resulting xml contains text from the source xml in the destination that was contained in tags that do not match my template criteria

I was expecting that my select *Group* in the first template to find any elements named *Group* that are immediate children of *CrystalReport* and pass them along in the apply template call. I understood that the match filter on my second template would only take in *Group*'s that have an attribute of *Level=1* and write them out. I'd expect **everything else** to be ignored.

Why does "not this" appear in my output?

source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--
 UPDATE: Note that adding the xmlns attribute causes all output
 to disappear unless you use Chris's second solution.
 -->
<CrystalReport xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail" >
  <Group Level="1">
    <GroupHeader>
      <Section>
        <Field FieldName="apple" />
      </Section>
    </GroupHeader>
    <Group Level="2">
      not this
    </Group>
  </Group>
</CrystalReport>
```

transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/CrystalReport">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Group"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Group[@Level='1']/GroupHeader">
    <tag1><xsl:value-of select="Section/Field/@FieldName"/></tag1>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <tag1>apple</tag1>
      not this
    </root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing the problem where the built in templates of the XML parser are coming into play. You are apply templates to all of the `Group` elements, but only catching one of them with your own templates. The other is handled by the default templates which out put the values of all nodes. I suggest that you change

```
 <xsl:template match="/CrystalReport">
```

into

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
```

This will override the root default templates which are producing the extra output. You can find more on the built in template rules at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule

Then override the basic text() template so you final XSLT looks a bit like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CrystalReport/Group"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Group[@Level='1']/GroupHeader">
    <tag1>
        <xsl:value-of select="Section/Field/@FieldName"/>
    </tag1>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

**UPDATE**

Or even simpler you could just match the desired elements and use something like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/CrystalReport">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Group[@Level='1']/GroupHeader"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="GroupHeader">
    <tag1>
        <xsl:value-of select="Section/Field/@FieldName"/>
    </tag1>
</xsl:template>
```

This will leave the default text() templates in place which can be very handy.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, I had read about the null template to match on text() but must have been using the non-root match on my base template

Comment: Glad it helped, your comment prompted me to add a slightly cleaner example using more of your original code.

Comment: My sample was a simplified example of the real problem, I've now discovered that adding the namespace back in to the CrystalReport element causes no data to be returned (xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"), I'm sure I've seen namespace solutions around, I'll take a look. Thanks for the update, I'll try that too.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:crystal="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/crystal:CrystalReport">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="crystal:Group[@Level='1']/crystal:GroupHeader"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="crystal:GroupHeader">
    <tag1>
        <xsl:value-of select="crystal:Section/crystal:Field/@FieldName"/>
    </tag1>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: the only change was the namespace declaration (now updated in the original question), there was no namespace defined on the elements in the xml body

Comment: That is very odd, I just tried my XSLT on your updated XML and it gives the desired output. Are you sure you copied the entire XSLT, specifically the xmlns:crystal="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail" reference at the top?

Comment: Ah, I had failed to appreciate the namespacing mechanism. I interpreted your answer to mean I had namespace prefixed xml element names in my source (in my defence the important bit scrolled off the code block), where as you *do* actually know what you are talking about ;-) and I on the other hand don't